# Data is still kept and won't restart back from zero

Tags: php

I have a quiz system where if the correct answer is chosen, the score will +1. But I clicked backspace once, and the score won't reset to 0 everytime I backspace. I tried re-answering the question, but the score is still kept and won't start back from 0

keep in mind tho i used 'skor' instead of 'score'

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
//GET SUBJECT ID 
session_start();
$topikpilihan=$_SESSION['topikpilihan'];
?>
<?php session_start(); ?>


//CHECK SCORE
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['skor'])){
$_SESSION['skor'] = 0;
}

//WHEN THE SELECTED ANSWER IS POSTED
if($_POST){
$idsoalan = $_POST['idsoalan'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$selected_choice = $_POST['pilihan'];
$nextsoalan=$number+1;
$totalsoalan=4;

//GET TOTAL QUESTIONS
$query="SELECT * FROM soalan where idtopik= '$topikpilihan'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($condb,$query);
$totalsoalan=mysqli_num_rows($result1);

//GET CORRECT ANSWER
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM soalan WHERE nosoalan = $number AND idsoalan=$idsoalan";
$result2 = mysqli_query($condb,$query2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$correct_choice=$row['jawapansoalan'];

//COMPARE SELECTED ANSWER AND CORRECT ANSWER
if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
$semakan="TEPAT";
$_SESSION['skor']++;
}
if($number == $totalsoalan){
header("Location: jawabsoalan-tamat.php");
exit();
} else {
header("Location: jawabsoalan-mula.php?semakan=".$semakan."&idtopik=".$topikpilihan."&n=".$nextsoalan."&skor=".
$_SESSION['skor']);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you think should be resetting your score to 0?

Comment: this one I think `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['skor'])) { $_SESSION['skor'] = 0; }`.

Comment: That line of code means "if the `skor` session variable isn't set at all, then set it to 0." If it's already set, then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should use `session_start()` before outputting starts. `?><?php` is likely to throw output. You also are open to SQL injections with this code. Parameterize the query and use prepared statements.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica so do I have to declare it 0 everytime it starts? Sorry, im a php noob.

Comment: @user3783243 This is just for a school project but I'll take note of that!